# How do you import two useStyles files into one typescript file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styles

This is what I tried, but it doesn't find a declaration file for module 'react-combine-styles' even after installing: npm install @types/react-combine-styles.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import useStyles from "./useStylesUserManager";
import useStylesModal from "../../useStylesModals" ;

const combinedStyles = combineStyles(useStyles, useStylesModal);

const UserManagerPage: React.FC = (props) => {
   const  classes  = combinedStyles;

return (
 --CODE--
);

};

export default withStyles(combinedStyles)(UserManagerPage);
```

Comment: `combineStyles` is not declared at all

Answer (score 0):

Just call both hooks:

```
const classes = {
    ...useStyles(),
    ...useStylesModal()
};
```

Comment: Such a simple solution! Thanks so much it worked.